# How to align messages in UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want to know how to set the alignment of delegate message of alert view. anyone has solution, plz reply with some code.

Answer (score 9):

You need to get alertView's subViews. Iterate through the array of subview's, it will be having one item of type UILable. Get that UILabel from subview array and for that you can set textAlignment property.

```
NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subviews;
 for(int x=0;x<[subViewArray count];x++){
 if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]])
  {
      UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  }

}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. There's a small typo, though: "subViews" on the first line should be "subview" :-)

Comment: it actually should be "subviews"! :D

Answer (score 9):

This is just a slightly simplified version of the previous answer but I like to keep things simple. :)

```
for (UIView *view in alert.subviews) {
    if([[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        ((UILabel*)view).textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

Comment: `UITextAlignmentLeft` is deprecated, use `NSTextAlignmentLeft`

Answer (score 1):

the code below is not work on iOS7, only before iOS7.

```
for (UIView *view in alert.subviews) {
    if([[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
       ((UILabel*)view).textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

the question [Align message in UIAlertView to left in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027083/align-message-in-uialertview-to-left-in-ios-7) solve this problem.