# Align text in a UIAlertView that has a scrollbar

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, text-alignment

If a UIAlertView contains a certain amount of text, the text display is automatically changed to have scrollbars. I would like this text to be centre-aligned.

Searching around for the solution provides [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392354/how-to-align-messages-in-uialertview). However, this does not work on a UIAlertView that contains scrollbars.

How do I align the text in such an alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not do this. It could break with any iOS update if Apple changes the way that UIAlertView is structured. That being said, you can do this:

```
for(id subview in alertView.subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [(UITextView *)subview setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
}
```