# TextAlign not working in UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview, text-alignment

I want to Aligned my message text in UIAlertView and here is my code but when i running this code the text appear as before and nothing change after for loop. i also want to increase my text? I am using this code [Align text in a UIAlertView that has a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113653/align-text-in-a-uialertview-that-has-a-scrollbar) right now.

```
UIAlertView *alret = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                delegate:nil
                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                otherButtonTitles:nil];
for(id subview in alret.subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [(UITextView *)subview setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];       
    }
}
[alret show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (UIView *view in alert.subviews) {
    if([[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        ((UILabel*)view).textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.