# Align message in UIAlertView to left in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova, uialertview

I want to left align message in `UIAlertView` to left in `iOS7`, i am able to do that in iOS 5.x and 6.x using `UITextAlignmentLeft` and `NSTextAlignmentLeft` and not on `iOS 7`.

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue?

Comment: It is not possible in iOS7. "You cannot customize the appearance of alert views:" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sten is right we can't customize appearance of UIAlertView in iOS 7, if you need you can made a custom Alert view code is available at https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Comment: I think it makes more sense if you can post the relevant code from that because the links may not exist in future