# Align Left AlertView Message in iOS8 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have created an alert view and I want to align the text of the alert view to left and use this code.

But the problem is that `(alert.subviews).count` is **0**.

Here is my code:

```js
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Details:", message: "Composer: abcdfg \nShow:sdfa\nPerformer:asdasdf\nLanguage:farsi\nFirst Line:asdfasdfagadf", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                   
for view in alert.subviews{
  if view.isKindOfClass(UILabel){
    (view as UILabel).textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
   }
}
println((alert.subviews).count)
alert.show()
```

I want to align the message to left but the subviews count for alert is 0

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027083/align-message-in-uialertview-to-left-in-ios-7 can help you

Comment: already saw this but dont want a custom uialert

Comment: Don't post screenshot of code. Post code as text. Image can be removed from remote server, and If we want to try your code, it's easier to copy/paste.

Answer (score 6):

Text of alert "Terms and condition" is left Aligned

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iosGeek", message: "Terms and Condition", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left

    let messageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: "Terms and Condition",
        attributes: [
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
        ]
    )

    alertController.setValue(messageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

## swift 5 Sample code

```
    let alertMessage = """
    You message:
    • Point 1
    • Point 2
    • Point 3
    • Point 4
    """
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    
    let attributedMessageText = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alertMessage,
        attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
        ]
    )
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Sample title", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            
    // set attributed message here
    alertController.setValue(attributedMessageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let actionBlock = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Block", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive) { (action) in
        self.callWebServiceBlockUserWithUserId(userId: self.arrUserBlocked[sender.tag].id, index: sender.tag)
    }
    
    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) { (action) in
    }
    
    
    alertController.addAction(actionBlock)
    alertController.addAction(actionCancel)
    
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this gist that creates an Alert with left aligned text. To the author of the gist -- thank you very much: https://gist.github.com/nvkiet/29e4d5b5bef0865ee159

Essentially, when creating the UIAlertController:

• provide `title`

• `message` = nil

• create a NSMutableAttributedString in the following way:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
let attributedMessage: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: message, // your string message here
    attributes: [
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
    ]
)
```

• Add the attributed string as a key on your alertcontroller:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

• Present the alert

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView not support textAlignment

you have to see for custom solution.

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Answer (score 0):

As per the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1) you cannot customize the appreance of [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802), please check **Appearance of Alert Views** section in the given link.

There are two ways i see of resolving this

1. Use any third party component which suits your requirement.
2. Ask your designer to present the information in some other manner for which you were using the alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this function, and call it wherever you need

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {

 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:
        message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    let attributedMessage: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: message, // your string message here
        attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
        ]
    )
    alertController.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in

    }))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```